# UnsatisfiedLinkError in JD-Eclipse plugin using Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, decompiler

When trying to decompile a class in Eclipse Indigo using version 0.1.3 of JD-Eclipse, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError. I use JDK 7 (64bit) in combination with the Eclipse Indigo 64 bit version.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/java/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/798/1/.cp/lib/linux/x86/libjd-eclipse.so: /usr/local/java/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/798/1/.cp/lib/linux/x86/libjd-eclipse.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
```